# Hide images in compiled apk

Tags: android

I have a list of images referenced from the res/drawable folder. I realized that these images can be viewed from the compiled apk file when the file is opened with a file compressor program such as winrar. Is there a way to hide my images so that they can't be so easily accessed by snooping users?

Comment: What are you trying to hide? Do those images contain a secret? Existence of those images is a secret?

Comment: yeah. you could say that. for example, a quiz app where the images get revealed only per level. or maybe an easter egg picture that will be revealed only when the user wins the game. if a user knew where to look, he can immediately see the images in the drawable folder in the apk itself.

Comment: You can try to do some common thing - download all these "top secret" files at first start and save them in your apps directory. But this will not save you from rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I see here is not saving your images inside the app. Instead, save them on your app server and get each image only when it's needed.

If your app don't have a server, you can save the images obfuscated inside your app (for example: base64 encoded or encrypted with a hard coded key). It won't stop a hacker but it will defend you from the common user.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it sounds like you want to use [Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

From the above link:

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.

Just google or search stackoverflow on how to use Internal Storage if you need more help outside the Android docs.

Comment: I'm really more concerned of the actual apk, where the apk can be opened and the files viewed,  and not the after installation scenario.